# PayPal PHP-SDK can't get paymentId and PayerID

Tags: php, api, paypal

So i am trying to get paymentId and PayerID to complete the transaction and change the user but for some reason i get Undefined index errors.

I tried everything i can possibly think and sadly its my first time using PayPals API so if you could give me a little help i would really appreciate it!

PHP code:

```
<?php

use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

require 'start.php';

if (!isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentId'], $_GET['PayerID'])) {

    die();  

}

if ((bool)$_GET['success'] === false) {

    die();

}


$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);

$execute = new PaymentExecution();

$execute->setPayerId($payerID);

try{

    $result = $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    die($e); 

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the samples provided here: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#payments

They should help you understand this properly.

In your case, make sure you are adding `success=true` and `success=false` in your return url and cancel url when creating a payment.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Thankfully i found the mistake and everything is working perfect!